# Erro ao calcular diferença entre datas no Entity com Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expressões-lambda

Antes estava assim minha expressão:

```
var resultado = db.T_CRM_StatusPDV
                              .Join(db.T_PDV, t1 => t1.DE_Cnpj, t2 => t2.CNPJ, (t1, t2) => new { t1, t2})
                              .Where(dt => (TimeSpan)((dt.t1.DT_TransacaoV - DateTime.Now)).TotalDays > 45
                                     && dt.t2.DataCadastro >= dataInicio && dt.t1.DT_ControleV >= dataControle)
                              .Select(i => new { i.t1.DE_Cnpj }).ToList();
```

Isso gerava esse erro:

```
DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type.
```

Alterei para essa expressão:

```
var resultado = db.T_CRM_StatusPDV
                              .Join(db.T_PDV, t1 => t1.DE_Cnpj, t2 => t2.CNPJ, (t1, t2) => new { t1, t2})
                              .Where(dt => EntityFunctions.DiffHours(dt.t1.DT_TransacaoV,DateTime.Now) > 45 
                                     && dt.t2.DataCadastro >= dataInicio && dt.t1.DT_ControleV >= dataControle)
                              .Select(i => new { i.t1.DE_Cnpj }).ToList();
```

E agora tenho esse erro:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32] DiffHours(System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime], System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

Como posso fazer cálculo de horas numa expressão lambda ou linq to entities?

Comment: Não é inteiro, é um DateTime. Esse campo vem direto do BD. É do tipo DateTime com certeza. Inclusive, Morrison, num exemplo em outro post, fizemos um cast para TimeSpan

Comment: Sim, tô testando outra coisa pra responder de novo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pro primeiro erro, troque:

```
.Where(dt => (TimeSpan)((dt.t1.DT_TransacaoV - DateTime.Now)).TotalDays > 45
```

Por:

```
.Where(dt => DbFunctions.DiffDays(dt.t1.DT_TransacaoV, DateTime.Now) > 45
```

Sobre o segundo, experimente trocar `EntityFunctions` por `DbFunctions`.

Comment: Vou tentar os dois e já posto o resultado aqui.

Comment: Ambas as soluções, estão dando esse erro: DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type. Vou tentar com DBFunctions

Comment: DBFunctions deu certo. Acho ser esse o caminho. Minha lista veio vazia, vou verificar alguns registros e ver o porque, mas pela minha pergunta, está ok. Se quiser alterar a resposta para DBFunctions, aí marco como resolvido.

Comment: @pnet Editei. Vamos tentar outra coisa.